# Резкое уменьшение размера Frame

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При расширении левый frame, ведёт себя надо,но при уменьшении он закрывается не плавно, а резко и при этом не до конца, потом проходит секунда и он закрывается до конца. Я думаю, что проблема в оранжевом frame-е с его размером, но конкретно в чём понять не могу

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1050, 653)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1050, 653))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1050, 653))
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0.263699 rgba(28, 33, 44, 255), stop:0.784247 rgba(41, 48, 60, 255));")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.root = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.root.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.root.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.root.setObjectName("root")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.root)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.frame_ = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.root)
        self.frame_.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 60))
        self.frame_.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 60))
        self.frame_.setStyleSheet("")
        self.frame_.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_.setObjectName("frame_")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_)
        self.frame_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 0))
        self.frame_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 16777215))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 45))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 45))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border:none;")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/Изображения/logo.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(55, 55))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(609, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_)
        self.frame_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 0))
        self.frame_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(5)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(15, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.miniBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_3)
        self.miniBtn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(26, 26))
        self.miniBtn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(26, 26))
        self.miniBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(97, 97, 97);\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    border-radius: 13;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color: rgb(134, 134, 134);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"}")
        self.miniBtn.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/Изображения/minus (2).svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.miniBtn.setIcon(icon1)
        self.miniBtn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(22, 22))
        self.miniBtn.setObjectName("miniBtn")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.miniBtn)
        self.closeBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_3)
        self.closeBtn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(26, 26))
        self.closeBtn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(26, 26))
        self.closeBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(97, 97, 97);\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    border-radius: 13;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color: rgb(134, 134, 134);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"}")
        self.closeBtn.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/Изображения/close (3).svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.closeBtn.setIcon(icon2)
        self.closeBtn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(22, 22))
        self.closeBtn.setObjectName("closeBtn")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.closeBtn)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_)
        self.frame_5 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.root)
        self.frame_5.setStyleSheet("")
        self.frame_5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_5.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_5.setObjectName("frame_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_5)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_5)
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(43, 589))
        self.frame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 16000))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(58, 65, 82);\n"
"border-radius: 20;")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(8, -1, -1, -1)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.frame_8 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_8.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 25))
        self.frame_8.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16000, 25))
        self.frame_8.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_8.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_8.setObjectName("frame_8")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_8)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_8)
        self.menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 25))
        self.menu.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16000, 25))
        self.menu.setStyleSheet("border:none;")
        self.menu.setText("")
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/Изображения/5050.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.menu.setIcon(icon3)
        self.menu.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(35, 34))
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_8)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 58, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.frame_6 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_6.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 25))
        self.frame_6.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(165, 58))
        self.frame_6.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_6.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_6.setObjectName("frame_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 9, 18, -1)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setSpacing(1)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_6)
        self.label_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.label_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../Изображения/gun1.png"))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.weapon = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_6)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.weapon.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.weapon.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.weapon.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(111, 40))
        self.weapon.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.weapon.setFont(font)
        self.weapon.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    color: rgb(78, 75, 94);      \n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: inset;\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);\n"
"    }")
        self.weapon.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.weapon.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(35, 35))
        self.weapon.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.weapon.setObjectName("weapon")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.weapon)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_6)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 338, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.frame_7 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_7.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 25))
        self.frame_7.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(165, 58))
        self.frame_7.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_7.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_7.setObjectName("frame_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_7)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 9, 9, -1)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_7)
        self.label_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(31, 31))
        self.label_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(31, 31))
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../Изображения/icons8-информация-30.png"))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.spravka = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_7)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.spravka.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.spravka.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.spravka.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(105, 40))
        self.spravka.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(105, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.spravka.setFont(font)
        self.spravka.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    color: rgb(78, 75, 94);\n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"\n"
"    }\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: inset;\n"
"   \n"
"    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);\n"
"    }")
        self.spravka.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.spravka.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(55, 55))
        self.spravka.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.spravka.setObjectName("spravka")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.spravka)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_7)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.frame_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_5)
        self.frame_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 589))
        self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_4.setObjectName("frame_4")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_4)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.frame_12 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_4)
        self.frame_12.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 370))
        self.frame_12.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 370))
        self.frame_12.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(175, 91, 22);")
        self.frame_12.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_12.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_12.setObjectName("frame_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_12)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(28, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addItem(spacerItem4)
        self.frame_9 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_12)
        self.frame_9.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 260))
        self.frame_9.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 260))
        self.frame_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(58, 65, 82);\n"
"border-radius: 23;")
        self.frame_9.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_9.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_9.setObjectName("frame_9")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_9)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.frame_9)
        self.textBrowser_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 260))
        self.textBrowser_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 260))
        self.textBrowser_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.textBrowser_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.frame_9)
        spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(32, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addItem(spacerItem5)
        self.frame_10 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_12)
        self.frame_10.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(220, 280))
        self.frame_10.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 280))
        self.frame_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(58, 65, 82);\n"
"border-radius: 23;")
        self.frame_10.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_10.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_10.setObjectName("frame_10")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_10)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.frame_10)
        self.textBrowser.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(220, 280))
        self.textBrowser.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.frame_10)
        spacerItem6 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(32, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addItem(spacerItem6)
        self.frame_11 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_12)
        self.frame_11.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 260))
        self.frame_11.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 260))
        self.frame_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(58, 65, 82);\n"
"border-radius: 23;")
        self.frame_11.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_11.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_11.setObjectName("frame_11")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_11)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.textBrowser_3 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.frame_11)
        self.textBrowser_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 260))
        self.textBrowser_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 260))
        self.textBrowser_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #6c6c00;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser_3.setObjectName("textBrowser_3")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.textBrowser_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.frame_11)
        spacerItem7 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(28, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addItem(spacerItem7)
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.frame_12)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.frame_4)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_5)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.root)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:18pt; color:#ffffff;\">Apex - Helper</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.weapon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Weapons"))
        self.spravka.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reference"))
        self.textBrowser_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">Информация</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-style:italic; color:#d4d4d4;\">Программа находится в разработке, поэтому, пока что присудствует не вся информация </span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">ApexHelper</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Эта программа предназначена для того, чтобы помочь новичкам или опытным игрокам более лучше освоить игру</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">_Apex Legends_</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Тут ты найдёшь подробное описание каждого оружия,</span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; text-decoration: underline;\"> </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">обвеса и прочих вещей.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;\">С уважением, Разработчик </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;\">ApexHelper</span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; color:#c2c2c2;\">.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_3.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; color:#c2c2c2;\">Кому принадлежит</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Все данные, изображения и прочее из программы, принадлежат компании</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\"> </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; color:#6f6f0a;\">Respawn Entertainment</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Никому более.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Их материал был повзаимствован для помощи игрокам.</span></p></body></html>"))
import icons_rc
```

Comment: не хватило место для кода, поэтому тут добавляю конец 

  if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

Comment: Никита то что вы написали в теле вопроса. достигается за счет логики анимации, которую вы не предоставили. Я проверил вашу форму, добавив `class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow): ... ` из моего ответа на ваш предыдущий вопрос. Все работает как надо. Только уберите строки `self.weapon.show()` и `self.weapon.hide()` и попробуйте.

Comment: @S.Nick Да действительно, это было в show и hide кнопки weapon. Но hide и show кнопки referense работают хорошо. Как же сделать так, чтобы кнопка weapon исчезала? Я уверен, что что-то не так с оранжевым frame-мом

Comment: нет, оранжевый frame здесь ни при чем.

Comment: Нижняя кнопка прекрасно исчезает, что же тогда может быть с кнопкой weapon?

Comment: #S.Nick Хотя я немного сказал не верно, при исчезании кнопки referense иконки сдвигаются с места